# Rails Model Calculation Only If Condition Met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I have an `item` model and need to calculate the total profit less any fees. I am currently doing that right now in the model. However, I want to be able to have that calculation run only once the boolean is updated to sold. I've tried an if statement in the model, but that didn't work.

item.rb

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  def profit_calc
    sold_for - bought_for - fees - shipping rescue 0
  end

  def self.purchase_total
    sum(:bought_for)
  end

  def self.fee_total
    sum(:fees)
  end

  def self.shipping_total
    sum(:shipping)
  end

  def self.sales_total
    sum(:sold_for)
  end

  def self.profit_total
    sum(:sold_for) - sum(:bought_for) - sum(:fees) - sum(:shipping)
  end

  scope :visible, -> { where(sold: false) }
  scope :sold, -> { where(sold: true) }
end
```

schema.rb

```
create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "description"
  t.float    "bought_for"
  t.float    "sold_for"
  t.float    "fees"
  t.float    "shipping"
  t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
  t.boolean  "sold",                default: false
end
```

statistics.html.erb

```
<td><%= number_to_currency(@items.profit_total) %></td>
```

Comment: Do you want to save `total_profit` to database after calculation?

Comment: @Muntasim No, that is not necessary.

Comment: @MikeWiesenhart can you use `after_save` with condition `if: :sold_changed?` and within the callback method you can check `do...something if self.sold?`

Comment: `sold` field in object level and your calculation is in class level, do you mean when some object's sold attribute will be set to true `total_profile` should consider those sold items?

Comment: @Muntasim There is a 'sell' button in one of my views that when I click it changes the boolean in the DB to true. I only want items that are true to be calculated in the 'profit_total'...does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sold` scope in the calculation:

```
  def self.profit_total
    sold.sum(:sold_for) - sold.sum(:bought_for) - sold.sum(:fees) - sold.sum(:shipping)
  end
```

But each time you call  `Item.profit_total` it will execute all the queries. You may want to cache the calculation if you need that frequently and expire the cache in after_save callback if that is sold.